# Add javascript onclick to radio button INPUT tag

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, webforms, code-behind

I have a javascript function and need to add it to some dynamically created radio buttons onclick from code behind.

I've tried - newRadioSelect.Attributes.Add("onlick", "javascript:toggle(this);")

The code above adds it to the span tag that the radio button creates, any ideas how to get it on the input tag of the radio buttons?

Thanks

J.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit like buses, nothing for ages then 2 come along at once.

I worked out a way to do it and got it working and then I received an answer from somewhere else, so thought I'd put them both on here.

My version (not the best)

```
        Dim newRadioYes As New RadioButton
        newRadioYes.Text = "Yes"
        newRadioYes.ID = "c_" & childID & "_school_selected_0"
        newRadioYes.Attributes.Add("onclick", "javascript:toggle(this, " & childID & ");")
        newRadioYes.Attributes.Add("value", "Yes")
        newRadioYes.GroupName = "c_" & childID & "_school_selected"

        Dim newRadioNo As New RadioButton
        newRadioNo.Text = "No"
        newRadioNo.ID = "c_" & childID & "_school_selected_1"
        newRadioNo.Attributes.Add("onclick", "javascript:toggle(this, " & childID & ");")
        newRadioNo.Attributes.Add("value", "No")
        newRadioNo.GroupName = "c_" & childID & "_school_selected"
```

Better version

```
        Dim newRadioSelect As New RadioButtonList
        newRadioSelect.RepeatDirection = RepeatDirection.Horizontal
        newRadioSelect.RepeatLayout = RepeatLayout.Flow
        newRadioSelect.Items.Add("Yes")
        newRadioSelect.Items.Add("No")
        newRadioSelect.Items(0).Attributes.Add("onclick", "javascript:toggle(this);")
        newRadioSelect.Items(1).Attributes.Add("onclick", "javascript:toggle(this);")
```

Thanks to those who helped.

Answer (score 0):

just use this javascript function, you don't need to explicit add it to the tags.

http://www.mediaevent.de/javascript/event_listener.html

```
newRadioSelect.addEventListener("click", myFunction, false); 

function myFunction(event){
    toggle(event.target);
}
```

Comment: sorry don't think i explained myself very well. I'm using asp.net and trying to add it from code behind.

Comment: oh sorry, i just saw that code and thougt it is javascript :)

Answer (score 0):

You can add attributes to your dynamic `RadioButton` in this fashion

`rb.Attributes["onClick"] = "javascript:alert('Hi');";`

Comment: Isn't that the same as i've got above but in C#? it adds it to the <span> tag that a .net RadioButtonList creates, i need it to be attached to the <input> tag.

Comment: well it is attached to the input tag.. Check the viewsource and you will see it.

Comment: i haven't tried it, i'm using VB and it's the same as what i'm currently using which adds the onclick to the <span> tag not the <input> tag.

Comment: Ok well try it if you get time.. works perfect on my machine !